# parent & show element in Laravel freamwork?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, frameworks

i'm learning Laravel frame work, and have a question:
in this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <nav>
    @section('nav')
      <a>Home page</a>
    @show
  </nav>

  <div id="content">
    @yield('content')
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

what to do: @show ?!

Comment: http://jafty.com/blog/tag/laravel-stop-and-show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a layout (layout.blade.php) view of

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <nav>
      @section('nav')
        <a>Home page</a>
      @show
    </nav>

    <div id="content">
      @yield('content')
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And a view (users.blade.php) of

```
@extends('layout')

@section('nav')
   > <a>Users</a>
@stop
```

You should see rendered:

```
Home page > Users
```

But you could also use stop on layout:

```
@section('nav')
  <a>Home page</a>
@stop
```

And @parent on your view:

```
@section('nav')
   @parent

   > <a>Users</a>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at video's 6 and 7 regarding "blade basics" and "master pages"

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch